# how to parse relatively complicated url with gson

Tags: java, json, gson

From the link :

http://api.crossref.org/works?rows=2

I am trying to parse json through GSON in java. Here is some part of my code:

```
public class crossref {
    public String status;
    public String messageType;
    public String messageVersion;
    public Message message;}

public class Message {
    public int itemsPerPage;
    public Query query;
    }

public class Query{
    public String searchTerms;
    public int startIndex;}

public class Items {
    public List subtitle;
    public List subject;
    public Issued issued;}

public class Issued{
   ??? }
```

At this point i am confused and could not be sure how to define structure. Can somebody help me? For ex. in the sample json, must "issued" part be list or listarray?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Parse it into Lists and Maps, then write constructors for all your target classes that accept a Map.  Each constructor cascades to it's "children".  Coding is quite straight-forward when done this way, and you can easily handle "oddball" cases.

Comment: Thanks @HotLicks. Indeed what i gave above as an example is android code that i found through stackoverflow. If I write it in java, would it be the same? In stackoverflow I always encountered samples for android. If so can you show me how to adjust this code to java?

Comment: ??? Android *is* Java.

Comment: You do know how to read JSON, right?  "issued" is an "object", but it only has one element, an array named "date-parts".  (Go to json.org and learn the JSON syntax -- it only takes 5-10 minutes.)

Comment: yes i already know it and i can parse a json formatted url result. but since i got some errors i thought may be there might be some small differences. may be it is better to edit my question.

Comment: "Small differences" in *what*?  JSON is JSON, Java is Java.  GSON, I can't say.

Answer (score 0):

issued contains a date-parts object, which is an array of array of int.

Try (not tested):

```
public class Issued {
  public List<List<Integer> date-parts;
};
```